# Send List of Parcelable Object Inside Parcelable Object to Another Activity Using Intent

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I already searched my question at Google and here on StackOverflow, but I can not find any question that is similar to mine.

I am new to Xamarin Android and I was trying to send a list of parcelable object inside a parcelable object to another activity using intent. Now, I can send that parcelable object to another activity, but the list inside the object is null.

My code is based on [this example](https://anupsamantaray.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/passing-custom-objects-between-activities)

Here's what i try so far:

*Group.cs*

```
public class Group : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Member> member { get; set; }
    public Group() { }
    public Group(string id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.member = new List<Member>();
    }

    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, [GeneratedEnum] ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteString(id);
        dest.WriteString(name);
        dest.WriteList(member);
    }

    [ExportField("CREATOR")]
    public static GroupParcelableCreator GroupCreator()
    {
        return new GroupParcelableCreator();
    }
}
```

*GroupParcelableCreator.cs*

```
public class GroupParcelableCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
{
    public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        List<Member> member = new List<Member>();
        Group group = new Group(source.ReadString(), source.ReadString());
        source.ReadList(member, new Member().Class.ClassLoader);
        group.member = member;
        return group;
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.Object[size];
    }
}
```

Inside the `WriteToParcel` method, i already checked in debug mode that the `member` do have members, but inside the `CreateFromParcel` method the `member` is null even though the `id` and `name` values are retrieved

Can someone please tell me where I did wrong, and guide me to the correct way?

**Edit 1**

This is the Member class

*Member.cs*

```
public class Member : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public Member() { }
    public Member(string id, string name, string age, string position)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, [GeneratedEnum] ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteString(id);
        dest.WriteString(name);
        dest.WriteString(age);
        dest.WriteString(position);
    }

    [ExportField("CREATOR")]
    public static MemberParcelableCreator MemberCreator()
    {
        return new MemberParcelableCreator();
    }
}
```

*MemberParcelableCreator.cs*

```
 public class MemberParcelableCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
{
    public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        return new Member(source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString(), source.ReadString());
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.Object[size];
    }
```

Comment: What is the _Member_ class, and shouldn't it be Parcelable as well?

Comment: @Kiliman The _Member_ class is parcelable as well, see **Edit 1**

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason your are not just serializing the data using something like JSON and chuck that in as a string in the bundle?

That would simplify things a lot. Keep your Group and Memeber classes, just remove the inheritance from Java.Lang.Object and IParcelable. You can also remove the constructors as you will only need to have public properties for this to work.

Populate your classes, then simply add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json (get it from NuGet).

Then you can get the JSON string like so:

```
var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(group);
```

Then you can chuck that into the intent bundle:

```
intent.PutExtra("myData", json);
```

Then in the other activity you can retrieve it like so:

```
var json = Intent.GetStringExtra("myData");
var myObject = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Group>(json);
```

Comment: I am new to xamarin and I want to learn how to use parcelable, that is the reason :). And I already tried using your method above, thanks anyway.

Comment: Basically don't use it unless you really have to.